# Change border color of participant

Tags: plantuml

Is it possible to change the border / font colors of a particicular `participant` without setting it globally using `skinparam`?

For a particular `participant` I need to have a different border + font color than defined in `skinparam`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution in the [docs](https://plantuml.com/style-evolution) using user defined styles:

```
skinparam useBetaStyle true

<style>
    ' scope to sequenceDiagram elements
    sequenceDiagram {
     ' define a new style, using CSS class syntax
     .todo {
      FontColor white
      LineColor #52A0DC
      BackgroundColor #52A0DC
     }
     .exists {
      LineColor #a9a9a9
      BackgroundColor #a9a9a9
     }
    }
}
</style>

participant Dockerfile <<todo>>
participant "AWS SSM" as SSM <<exists>>
```

Result as expected:

[image]